# Defining styles for the very first blockquote of the page

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say I have an html page containing 3 blockquotes. How to set background of the very first blockquote (of the page) to red **with css** without using classes?

I already tried...

```
body blockquote: first-child {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

...without success.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439321/matching-first-element-in-whole-document (not vtc'ed, just linking).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with CSS alone in the general case. There is no “first descendant of a type” selector, only “first child of a type”.

Usually, however, assumptions can be made about the markup. For definiteness, assume that the page content is inside `<div id=content>...</div>` and that all `blockquote` elements appear as children of that element. Then you can just use the `:first-of-type` selector:

```html
<style>
#content blockquote:first-of-type {
    background-color: red;    
}
</style>
<div id=content>
<p>Some stuff
<blockquote>I am quoted.</blockquote>
<p>Some more stuff
<blockquote>I am quoted, too.</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried as you suggest... here is the test page: http://testjeanschwartz.weebly.com/ the problem is that the parent content I tried to use is `.container` but this is not a direct parent of the blockquote and it does not seems to work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato, in that case, the general part of the answer applies: you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

### Why your CSS doesn't work :

**Your HTML structure :**

```
body
__ parent
____ blockquote
__ parent
____ blockquote
```

**CSS :**

```
body blockquote: first-child {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

What this CSS selector actually does is - it selects every `blockquote` which occurs first in **its parent** and **not body**.

First-child doesn't work respective to the body tag when the elements are nested in other elements. It works respective to the parent.

**Try using this instead** :

```
td.wsite-multicol-col:first-child blockquote {
    background: red;
}
```

This selects the first `col` and sets styles for its child (`blockquote`). It doesn't set style to **first** blockquote of the page.

Comment: It is working for the first blockquote of the first `col` as you said. But how to  set style for the first blockquote of the page ? Assuming there may be several `col` on the page ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I updated the demo page http://testjeanschwartz.weebly.com to show the problem of having 2 blockquotes getting the style when I only need the 1st one.

Comment: You can't do it in CSS with such deeply nested markup. You can try JS.